# I am have trouble getting my if statements and cases to run

Tags: excel, vba, case

I am trying to add information into a column with existing information. I do not want to overwrite the existing values. The goal is to use select and if statements to evaluate criteria then add the new results to the column without overwriting existing info.

The first select statement works but replacing not cloud with "null" but now I need the second select to work if the cells are empty.

I have tried several if statements and now moved to switch case so multiple conditions can be evaluated.

```vb
Dim Bucket As String
Bucket = .Cells(i, "FI").value     

Select Case Bucket
  Case "Decommissioned/Retired", "DR Enabled", NO_DR, "Vendor", "Cloud"
      .Cells(i, "FI") = .Cells(i, "FI")
  Case "Not Cloud"
      .Cells(i, "FI") = ""

  If IsEmpty(Bucket) = True Then
    Select Case DR_Ready
      Case "BDC", "SDC","BDC;#CDC","SDC ;#Externally" 
        "BDC;#CDC;#NDC;#IDC;#SDC" 
      .Cells(i, "FI") = "DR in Place (Not in Program)"
    End Select
  End If

End Select
```

I am looking for "DR In Program" to be placed in the empty cells that meet the condition presented in the case containing DR_Ready.

Comment: Replace the if line with `Case ""`

Comment: Also where did you set the `DR_Ready` to check the `Select Case`?

Comment: It's set right above. Not pictured in the code i posted.                             
      DR_Ready = GetCellValue(.Cells(i, "EF"))

Comment: FWIW `Select Case` is just a (perhaps cleaner) alternative to `If...ElseIf...ElseIf...`; combining `Select Case` and `If...Then` statements feels a bit wrong, as an earlier (now deleted) comment alluded to.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I removed the if statement and was able to get the code running

Comment: @MathieuGuindon can you post as answer so this gets listed as closed?

Comment: @Cyril done.. hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bucket` is assigned before the `Select` block; that local variable is holding a copy of the value of `.Cells(i, "FI").value` *at the time of that assignment* - which means `.Cells(i, "FI") = ""` isn't affecting its value.

`If IsEmpty(Bucket)` (note: `= True` is redundant) will always be `False` regardless: it's running in the `"Not Cloud"` case, and `Bucket` can never be both `"Not Cloud"` and `Empty`.

That said, `""` isn't `Empty`; even if assigning `.Cells(i, "FI") = ""` somehow affected `Bucket`, `If IsEmpty(Bucket)` would still be `False`. Looks like you want the body of that nested `If` block to be executed unconditionally inside the `"Not Cloud"` case - but that's mere speculation.